# Azure - Files in file share with given extension

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share) to connect to Azure File Share and upload a file. I would like to chose what extension file will have, but I can't. I got an error shown below. If I remove `.txt` everything works fine. Is there a way to specify file extension while uploading it?

Error:

```
Exception: ResourceNotFoundError: The specified parent path does not exist.
```

Code:

```
def main(blobin: func.InputStream):
    file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<con_string>", 
                                                            share_name="data-storage", 
                                                            file_path="outgoing/file.txt")


    f = open('/home/temp.txt', 'w+')
    f.write(blobin.read().decode('utf-8'))
    f.close()

    # Operation on file here

    f = open('/home/temp.txt', 'rb')
    string_to_upload = f.read()
    f.close()

    file_client.upload_file(string_to_upload)
```

Comment: How are you uploading the file? Can you check if the file exists in the share?

Comment: @GauravMantri I take the string `string_to_upload`, make some operations and upload it using: `file_client.upload_file(string_to_uplad)`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the complete code for uploading? Also, please check if the file is uploaded properly. You can use Microsoft's Storage Explorer for that.

Comment: @GauravMantri file is properly uploaded if I use `file_path="outgoing/file"`. When I use `file_path="outgoing/file.txt"` it crashes on above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because `outgoing` folder doesn't exist in your file service share. I took your code and ran it with and without extension and in both situation I got the same error.

Then I created a folder and tried to upload the file and I was able to successfully do so.

Here's the final code I used:

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareFileClient, ShareDirectoryClient

conn_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=myaccountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

share_directory_client = ShareDirectoryClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string, 
                                                        share_name="data-storage",
                                                        directory_path="outgoing")

file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string, 
                                                        share_name="data-storage", 
                                                        file_path="outgoing/file.txt")

# Create folder first.
# This operation will fail if the directory already exists.
print "creating directory..."
share_directory_client.create_directory()
print "directory created successfully..."

# Operation on file here
f = open('D:\\temp\\test.txt', 'rb')
string_to_upload = f.read()
f.close()

#Upload file
print "uploading file..."
file_client.upload_file(string_to_upload)
print "file uploaded successfully..."
```

Comment: Indeed, when it took the name of the `blobin`, it included its directory.